# JSF create dynamic commandLinks

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm working on a Maven project with Eclipse Mars.2, Java 1.8 update 102 for 64bits, JSF Mojarra 2.2.2, Primefaces 6.1, Spring 3.2.3, Hibernate 4.3 (MySQL 5.1.39) and Tomcat 7.0.53.

I have 2 xhtml pages with their respective @ViewScoped backing beans. In **page A** I have the following code:

```
<p:dataGrid var="theReg" value="#{pageA_BB.listOfReg}" columns="1" rows="5" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom">
    <p:commandLink value="#{theReg.title}" action="pageB?faces-redirect=true&amp;idvalue=#{theReg.paramValue}" />
</p:dataGrid>
```

The above code is supposed to render some URLs with different param values. The **theReg.title** is a String and the **theReg.paramValue** is an Integer

In **page B** backing bean I have the following code to rescue and use the "idvalue" parameter:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("idvalue")!=null){
        idvalue = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("idvalue"));
    }else{
        idvalue = 0;
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work because EL is not allowed inside commandLink action.

I have tried to use a f:param as described [here](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/) but the use of f:params require the backing bean to be @Requestscope (other way a scope error triggers) and I need a @Viewscoped because some Primefaces components require it.

I have thought about using EL inside an onClick event like that:

```
<p:commandButton onclick="window.open('pageB.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&amp;idvalue=#{theReg.paramValue}', '_blank')" value="#{theReg.title}"/>
```

But I would like to use params as I feel it would be the "cleanest" method.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Where did you read _"EL is not allowed inside commandLink action."_

Comment: I didn't read it anywhere, I just execute the code above and it triggers an EL error, but if I change the "pageB?faces-redirect=true&amp;idvalue=#{theReg.paramValue}" by "pageB?faces-redirect=true&amp;idvalue=7777" it works... It seems some kind of limitation because using the "onclick" option I describe it works... Take into account that "theReg" is a local variable of a p:dataGrid

Comment: If you get an error, post what error... And if it is the var of the datagrid then that might indeed not work since that is used render time. Might be an option to call a method , pass the page and value and in that method return the relevant string you now construct in the attribute

Comment: I think that is the point, it is used in render phase. I also tried what you describe with:
`<p:commandLink value="#{theReg.title}" action="#{pageA_BB.exampleMethod(#{theReg.paramValue})}" />`

And this method in **page A** backing bean:

`public String exampleMethod(String val) {
  return "pageB?faces-redirect=true&amp;idvalue="+val;
 }`

It also doesn't work...